# Write a S3 Select query to exclude a carriage return(\r) rows

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-s3-select

I have a csv column that has data with \r character. How can write a query to eliminate such data

```
SELECT rv FROM s3object s
```

this gives me:

[image]

I don't want such rows. Want to eliminate it all.

This query still returns me the same results

```
SELECT rv FROM s3object s where rv!='\r'
```

Comment: what's the datatype of rv column?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the rows with digits? It might be possible to use `WHERE rv > 0` or something like that.

Comment: {"rv": "61\r"},{"rv": "62\r"},{"rv": "63\r"} .......... 
These are just mere numbers in that rv column in the csv file, but with s3 select I get this kind of output.
@JohnRotenstein

Comment: Some rows contain 2-digit numbers and some rows are empty. And these empty ones have "\r" when parsed as json in the output @eshirvana

Comment: Oh! They also have the `\r` in that column! What does the file itself look like, if you open it in a Text Editor?

Comment: `CUST_AMT,RV
23.33, 
 200,61 
300,62 
400,63 `

This is how it looks like when opened with a text editor @JohnRotenstein

Comment: That format looks confusing -- there are spaces in strange places, or perhaps they are the `\r` characters. Do the values have commas to indicate decimals (eg `400,63` is the same as `400.63` using the European standard)? If so, why does `23.33` not follow this format? I was hoping to reproduce your situation, but I still can't see enough to create a similar input file with the \r characters.

Comment: https://controlc.com/22ac9244
This is the exact csv data paste file when opened with text editor @JohnRotenstein
The first row is the header row and the last column is the RV column causing the problem.

Comment: I copied that data into a file and ran the query and there were no `\r` characters. I think this is because they are non-text characters, so when you used Copy & Paste, they didn't copy across. I'd need the actual BINARY file to test it, rather than a Copy & Paste of the visible text.

Comment: shorturl.at/fFS49
Here's a link to the file @JohnRotenstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has `0x0d 0x0a` (CR LF) at the end of each line. This is often generated by Windows software.

It appears that S3 Select doesn't know how to handle the combination, so the `\r` is treated as part of the last field.

You can 'fix' this by ignoring the last character of the last field:

```sql
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(rv FROM 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(rv) - 1) AS rv
FROM s3object s
WHERE char_length(rv) > 1 -- Optional
```

Comment: `FOR CHAR_LENGTH(rv) - 1` this part can be ignored? as default is till the end of the string

Comment: No, you can't ignore that. The `\r` is appended to the **end** of the field, so you need to tell S3 Select to only retrieve the substring up to, but not including, the last character.